# Hibernate manyToMany join on non-@Id

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

Having some trouble doing a many to many hibernate join.

With the folowing database:

```
Table assetgroup:   groupid, assetid
Table group:        id, name
Table view asset:   id, assetid, name
```

I'm trying to do a join in hibernate. Note that the "asset" class represents a view of larger data, so the id column is not the one I want to use in a join, but it is the unique element for that view (or a composite could be used)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assetview")
public class AssetView {
    @Column(name="assetid")  
    public Long    assetid;

    @Id  @Column(name="id")       
    public Long    id;

    @Column(name="name")       
    public String  name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="assets")
    public List<Group> groups;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="groups")
public class Groups {
    @Id @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")       
    public String  name;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "assetgroup",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "groupid"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "assetid")
    )
    public List<Asset> assets;
}
```

The above almost works, in that I can see hibernate doing a query to join the values in, however it is using the wrong id value from the "Asset" class. I need it to join on "assetid" instead the trace shows id doing a fetch with a value from the "id" column.

I thought that setting a referencedColumnName would help

```
inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "assetid", referencedColumnName="assetid")
```

but all I get is an exception at deploy

```
 property [...Group_assets] not found on entity [Group]
```

I'm beginning to think hibernate can't do what I want as my database has links that aren't the @Id values for hibernate - is there any way to force this?

I am going to want to filter based on the Group object later, so I think I'm going to need this as part of the model, rather than doing an explicit fetch later.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `referencedColumnName="assetid"` instead of `referencedColumnName="vodassetid"`? What this `vod` prefix in `vodassetid`, you didn't mention it anywhere else in the question?

Comment: Ah, yes - copy+paste error